# mySQL Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE location='/mgc_cb_evo.php?do=view_chatbox' 
GROUP BY userid
```

I am using mySQL

I want the query to only return rows that have a lastactivity of 15 minutes ago. I believe lastactivity is timedate but it may just be time. So if you could provide the answer for both that would be great.

The above query returns all of the results but I only want results which have a last activity of less than 15 minutes ago. The time on my forums are GMT+1 if that helps.

Also some userid's have multiple rows so I only want to get the latest row, which can be determined using lastactivity, with a userid.

Can someone help me. If you could provide the actual code that would help me a lot as I have to rush to work soon.

THANKS!

Comment: What's the name and type of the column storing this data?   What have you tried that isn't working?  Filtering by date/time should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the current time `INTERVAL` to specify time range

```
select *
from session
where location='/mgc_cb_evo.php?do=view_chatbox' 
  and lastactivity >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 900
```

You might not need the `GROUP BY` because it is usually used for aggregation like `SUM(x)`.

Comment: I understand that but it didn't work. It returned 0 rows, I know there should be at-least 1 row. Could it be that the timestamp isn't giving the same timestamp that is being used when the row is submitted? My forum time is GMT+1 but I think the server time may be something else. How can I find out the difference?

Comment: @user3474238, run `select current_timestamp` and see what's server's current time

Comment: 2014-06-13 02:52:58 This is what I the lastactivity in the session column looks like: 1402636595

Comment: what about `select max(lastactivity) from session`?

Comment: 1402639077 <--- Result. I have to go now. I will be on for 1 minute so please wait for about 10 hours :p

Comment: lastactivity looks like  unix timestamp. If so try `and lastactivity >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 900` (ie, 900 seconds in 15 minutes)

Comment: Great! That worked Kickstart - if you make that an answer I can mark it is correct.

Comment: Probably best to allow @Fabricator to modify their answer to recognise that it is a unix timeestamp and then mark theirs as correct. They have done most of the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE location='/mgc_cb_evo.php?do=view_chatbox' 
AND lastactivity = addtime(curtime(),'-1500');
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Except he wants everything _more recent_ than 15 minutes ago.  You should never do a direct comparison for filtering with a timestamp you haven't seen before/have no control over; there's too much chance there _isn't_ a matching value (which tells you nothing useful).

Comment: You are most welcome with your suggestions. For this the user can change the comparison from `=` to `>=`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE location='/mgc_cb_evo.php?do=view_chatbox' AND MINUTE(SUBTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),lastactivity))<15
GROUP BY userid
```

Check this, This should work for you

Comment: Won't work, should generate syntax errors.  `SUBTIME(...)` seems to take an _interval_ as the second parameter.  The output is a new timestamp, of which extracting `MINUTE(...)` will yield results... every hour/day/month/year (so it gets incorrect results).  Oh, and it'd ignore indices, too.